# Two different links to an image in a bucket? What's the difference?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

While ago I've uploaded an image to the Google Cloud Platform bucket and made it public. Direct link, from GCP looks like this:

[image: GCP Bucket View]

But this link, when put as Avatar URL to the Hangouts Chat API is not working (showing default avatar on hangouts chat, instead of mine).

I also found a way to create an url, its: https://storage.googleapis.com/[bucket]/[file] and this one is working, no idea why.

And my question is, why "official" link is not working, while the second one is working? What's the difference between them, difference between storage.cloud.google.com vs storage.googleapis.com?

Comment: The `URI` is used for the Google Client SDK - the `gs:` represents the protocol. Web browsers do not understand that protocol. The `Link URL` is used for HTTP (web client) access - the `https:` represents the HTTP protocol which web browsers do understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you understand better what's the difference between the two links.

> Access to public objects
>   All requests to the storage.cloud.google.com URI require authentication. This applies even when allUsers have permission to access an object. If you want users to download anonymously accessible objects without authenticating, use the storage.googleapis.com URI documented in Direct API requests. For details and examples, see Accessing Public Data.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#cookieauth) you have more information on the topic.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!

So what I understand is that users cannot authentiacate through Hangouts Chat and that's why they cannot see this bot avatar? But on the other hand, they are logged with their e-mail, so is there authentiaction needed?

Comment: Hey, glad that it helped, as I understand it, when you authenticate to Hangouts it's a different process from authenticating to your bucket permissions, let me explain, if you authenticate to hangouts it doesn't mean that they are authenticated to open your bucket link.